# Can I determine exactly which Atheros wireless network adapter I have?

Tags: wifi, hardware, lshw, inxi

I have a "Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter" installed. But - I need to determine exactly what the model is, i.e. what numbers replace those x's.

Unfortunately, I'm not near the machine physically and can't do it the old-fashioned way (= open it up, screw it out and check). And the box and booklet have been left in a different country...

So, can I determine exactly what I've got?

I'll mention that so far I've tried `lspci`, `lshw -c net` and `inxi -n`. I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux Beowulf (kernel version 5.2.17-1).

```
#  lspci | grep -i wireless
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
# lspci -n -s  04:00.0
04:00.0 0280: 168c:0030 (rev 01)
```

Comment: so what is the output of `lspci | grep -i wireless` ?

Comment: @binarysta: See edit.

Comment: AR93xx is a valid name and the `VendorID: ProductID` is `168c:0030`. please have a look at https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k and https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:168c-0030-1186-3a7e and https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/ATH9K_HW.html

Answer (score 1):

With `lspci` you can get the information about PCI buses in the system and devices connected to them

```
lspci | grep -i wireless

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Please note the pci bus info (for example it is **02:00.0** in my laptop)

You can get more detailed info with

```
lspci -vv -s  02:00.0

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NB037H 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [AR9002WB-1NGCD]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at de800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

with `sudo lspci -vv -s  02:00.0` you can get all capabilities and Device Serial Number.

For product ID

```
lspci -n -s 02:00.0
02:00.0 0280: 168c:002b (rev 01)
```

`VendorID:ProductID` code of the device is `168c:002b`